# View is not in the Window Hierarchy Error

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview, presentviewcontroller

I am running into an error where my view controller is dismissed upon attempting to upload a file.

Basically, the issue is that I have a WKWebView, that loads a website. Within this website, there is an "Upload File" button which needs a picture. The screen then proceeds to show the option of using Camera / Photo Library.

I tried adding all the corresponding pList Privacy settings, but when the "Upload File" button is clicked the View-Controller (Shown via Push) dismisses back to the home screen and gives me the following error:

Warning: Attempt to present UIImagePickerController on UINavigationController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

This is my code

import UIKit
import WebKit

class BizOwnerVC: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

```
var NewWebView: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    NewWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    NewWebView.uiDelegate = self
    view = NewWebView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myURL = URL(string: "https://cdlcheck.knack.com/dl-check#logged-in/")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    NewWebView.load(myRequest)
}
```

Comment: there is no present code

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the code is now present!

Comment: but this is the error Attempt to present UIImagePickerController on UINavigationController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: Yes, I have no idea why trying out different things

Comment: show ur reated code

Comment: @C.Doe were you able to figure out the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to dismiss the ViewController containing the WKWebView before I opened the other window. Hope this helps somebody

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code to the View Controller which contains the Web View :

```
override func dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) 
{
    if self.presentedViewController != nil {
        super.dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Comment: Still gave me the same error, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Which iOS version are you using and is it simulator or device?

Comment: iOS 10, and I get the same issue with both

Comment: How are presenting the view controller containing webview. Present it modally.